# Reverse 'gulp transpile' javascript file to original

Tags: node.js, gulp, babeljs, reverse

i have javascript file that is created using `gulp transpile` command. i want to get original javascript file. how can i get the original js file ? Is there any javascript module or gulp command to reverse this command ?

Thanks

This is a part of transpiled js file:

```
 ....
 var _regeneratorRuntime = require('babel-runtime/regenerator')['default'];

var _Object$assign = require('babel-runtime/core-js/object/assign')['default'];

var _interopRequireDefault = require('babel-runtime/helpers/interop-require-default')['default'];

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
    value: true
});

var _bluebird = require('bluebird');

var _bluebird2 = _interopRequireDefault(_bluebird);

var _logger = require('../logger');

var _logger2 = _interopRequireDefault(_logger);
var _jimp = require('jimp');

var _jimp2 = _interopRequireDefault(_jimp);

var gulCommands = {},
    commands = {},
    helpers = {},
    extensions = {},
    crawlerBoostrap = {};

gulCommands.findEditTextViews = function callee$0$0() {
    var context, params, elements;
    return _regeneratorRuntime.async(function callee$0$0$(context$1$0) {
        while (1) switch (context$1$0.prev = context$1$0.next) {
            case 0:
                context = '';
                params = {
                    "strategy": "xpath",
                    "selector": "//android.widget.EditText",
                    context: context,
                    multiple: true
                };
                context$1$0.next = 4;
                return _regeneratorRuntime.awrap(crawlerBoostrap.sendAction('find', params));

            case 6:
            case 'end':
                return context$1$0.stop();
        }
    }, null, this);
};
 ....
```